# Angular 9 Service with Subject.subscribe not working outside module

Tags: angular, observable, angular9, angular-library, subject-observer

I made a simpler version of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62150295/angular-9-service-as-obesrvable-in-library).

Service code:

```
import { Injectable, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {
private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('service');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { 
  }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }
}
```

Component that subscribe to the service:

```
this.notificationService.currentMessage.subscribe(message=> console.log(message));
```

When firing changeMessage from any component inside the library project

```
this.notSrv.changeMessage("TEST");
```

it works fine

When trying to do it from component inside application, which imports library

```
imports: [
    ...
    NineGoldLibModule,
    ...
  ],
```

Next is not triggered.

**Edit:**

**nine-gold-lib.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NineGoldLibComponent } from './nine-gold-lib.component';
import { NgHeaderComponent } from './common/ng-header/ng-header.component';
import { NgStylesComponent } from './common/ng-styles/ng-styles.component';
import { NgFooterComponent } from './common/ng-footer/ng-footer.component';
import { NgNavigationComponent } from './shared/ng-navigation/ng-navigation.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgLoginComponent } from './shared/forms/ng-login/ng-login.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormFieldComponent } from './directives/form-field/form-field.component';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse';
import { AccordionModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { NgRegisterComponent } from './shared/forms/ng-register/ng-register.component';
import { NotificationComponent } from './shared/notification/notification.component';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BookTrackerErrorHandlerService } from './services/book-tracker-error-handler.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [NineGoldLibComponent, NgHeaderComponent, NgStylesComponent, NgFooterComponent, NgNavigationComponent, NgLoginComponent, FormFieldComponent, NgRegisterComponent, NgRegisterComponent, NotificationComponent],
  imports: [RouterModule, CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, BsDropdownModule.forRoot(), BrowserAnimationsModule, NgSelectModule, CollapseModule.forRoot(),
    AccordionModule.forRoot(), ModalModule.forRoot(), FontAwesomeModule, ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: [NineGoldLibComponent, NgHeaderComponent, NgStylesComponent, NgFooterComponent, NgNavigationComponent, NgLoginComponent, FormFieldComponent, NgRegisterComponent, NotificationComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: BookTrackerErrorHandlerService }]
})
export class NineGoldLibModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NineGoldLibModule } from 'nine-gold-lib';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { GeneratorComponent } from './pages/generator/generator.component';
import { ToolsComponent } from './pages/tools/tools.component';
import { DownloadsComponent } from './pages/downloads/downloads.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './pages/admin/admin.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse';
import { AccordionModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    GeneratorComponent,
    ToolsComponent,
    DownloadsComponent,
    AdminComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NineGoldLibModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CollapseModule.forRoot(),
    AccordionModule.forRoot(),
    NgSelectModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Found this example for you https://medium.com/@billingpuneet.13/how-to-subscribe-to-a-variable-in-angular-7-1ec7087c3e9a

Comment: Can you show me NineGoldLibModule?

Comment: @Marc, I added both NineGoldLibrary module and app.module.ts. The service is prodivedIn: root.

Comment: @Avinash.Byalihal, this is fine, I have my code working up to this point, but If I will put that service and child-a component into one moduleA and child-b into appModule, (and import moduleA to appModule), the service will work for fine when called from child-a, but not, from child-b. I can try fork this stackblitz and share.